# Multiple XenDesktop 4 environments - dns confusion

Tags: domain-name-system, xendesktop

I have 2 HP proliant blade servers in an hp c3000 enclosure, EACH has xenserver 6.2 sp1 installed, a number of XP machines, one win2k3-r2 as a domain controller and another win2k3 as a xendesktop 4 desktop delivery controller.

Now the tutorial for xendesktop forces me to set a dns server role for the domain controller. hence i have 2 dns servers, one for each env. Everything is on the same network, along with a gateway and fileserver on a third blade. Things are working okay, sometimes laggy and i dont know if its a dns hang or not. im pretty sure this is not how the configuration should be.
to be more clear, the xp on XS1 have set their own domain controller as a dns server, the second batch has set the other domain controller as a dns server. how about the VMs who cant belong to a domain like the fileserver or application server? and what about the gateway and dhcp configuration for internet connectivity?  right now, the dhcp gives out all 3 dns servers (counting the third one for WAN) but arent i messing up with this configuration?